# Difference between computed property and property set with closure in swift 3?

Tags: swift, properties, computed-properties

I have read this ([Difference between computed property and property set with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515805/difference-between-computed-property-and-property-set-with-closure)) helpful question but it doesn't fully answer something i'd like to know.

It answers the difference between:

```
//closure
var pushBehavior: UIPushBehavior = {
    let lazilyCreatedPush = UIPushBehavior()
    lazilyCreatedPush.setAngle(50, magnitude: 50)
    return lazilyCreatedPush
}()
```

and

```
//computed
var pushBehavior: UIPushBehavior {
    get{
        let lazilyCreatedPush = UIPushBehavior()
        lazilyCreatedPush.setAngle(50, magnitude: 50)
        return lazilyCreatedPush
    }
}
```

I understand this. Now if we change the first one what is the difference between the computed variable in the second example and this:

```
var pushBehavior: UIPushBehavior {
    let lazilyCreatedPush = UIPushBehavior()
    lazilyCreatedPush.setAngle(50, magnitude: 50)
    return lazilyCreatedPush
}
```

To me this acts exactly like the get{} but without the get keyword. Is that the case and if so why do we have the get keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the `get` keyword and its braces.