# What is the advantage of closure stored property Initialisation?

Tags: swift, properties, initialization

What is the difference and the advantages/disadvantages of this code when initialising a property of a class as:

1.

```
let menuBar:MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb
    }()
```

and:

2.

```
let menuBar = MenuBar()
```

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515805/difference-between-computed-property-and-property-set-with-closure

Comment: In this particular case there is "no" difference in use. 1. is better if you are reusing UI elements, it packs the initialization instructions in a closure (function) and executes it() then stores it in your constant.

For example, if you customize mb.background or whatever it will be useful, or for a label with a particular font, a UIImage with a particular scale mode ...

Answer (score 5):

Both of the code snippets declare and initialize *[stored properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255)*, but in the first one it is initialized by closure. The reason why you should set a stored property with a closure is: there is a requirement(s) to do customization (calling a method for instance); [Adapted from The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1) - Initialization: Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232):

> If a stored property’s default value requires some customization or
>   setup, you can use a closure or global function to provide a
>   customized default value for that property. Whenever a new instance of
>   the type that the property belongs to is initialized, the closure or
>   function is called, and its return value is assigned as the property’s
>   default value.

Which means that you would be able to do:

```
let menuBar:MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    // for example, you'd need to call "doSomething" method
    // before returning the instance:
    menuBar.doSomething()
    return mb
}()
```

**Note that** in the body of the stored property closure, you would be not able to able to use the other properties in your class/struct since they considered as not being initialized yet. Example:

```
struct MyType {
    let myString = "My String!"
    let myInt: Int = {
        let anInt = 101

        // this won't work
        print(myString)

        return anInt
    }()
}
```

The result of the above code snippet is getting a compile-time error:

> error: instance member 'myString' cannot be used on type 'MyType'
>   print(myString)

---

**Furthermore** at some point, it would be recommended to declare your property as *lazy*:

```
lazy var menuBar:MenuBar = {
     let mb = MenuBar()
     // for example, you'd need to call "doSomething" method
     // before returning the instance:
     menuBar.doSomething()
     return mb
 }()
```

Means that:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not
>   calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored
>   property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.