# When isn't necessary to initialize lazy variable with lambda execution?

Tags: swift

As common, many swift developers initialize lazy variables by lambda execution. But I can't understand why they use lambda when it is one line of computation. What is the different between the following code examples?

```
var x = 7
var y = 9
lazy var z = x * y
```

```
var x = 7
var y = 9
lazy var z: Int = { 
    return x * y 
}()
```

I am new in swift, and from a naïve point of view the difference looks like that:

- the first one sample computes `x * y` immediately **but** initializes value by the lazy way
- the second one sample computes **and** initializes by the lazy way.

Is it correct?

---

This question isn't duplication of 
[What is the advantage of closure stored property Initialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571059/what-is-the-advantage-of-closure-stored-property-initialisation) because it is about lazy computation.

Comment: Style choice? I mean you can use lambdas on normal properties as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of closure stored property Initialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571059/what-is-the-advantage-of-closure-stored-property-initialisation)

Comment: Customization obviously. The reasons in the proposed duplicate are the same

Comment: When I googled 'lazy in swift' I found `{ ... }()` without object customization as the common case in the top link and in many other descriptions. Now I understand that there is no difference. But only the link to duplication question (that I couldn't google before) in combination with comments explained me the difference. But ok, I voted to close question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who do it the second way are making a mistake, that’s all.

The mistake is an easy one. Sometimes (1) a define-and-call initializer is necessary, namely when you need multiple code statements to obtain the initial value of a variable:

```
let timed : Bool = {
    if val == 1 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}()
```

Sometimes (2) you need lazy initialization, namely in order to mention `self` during property initialization:

```
lazy var arrow : UIImage = self.arrowImage()
```

And sometimes (3) you need both together to do both things:

```
lazy var prog : UIProgressView = {
    let p = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    p.alpha = 0.7
    p.trackTintColor = UIColor.clear
    p.progressTintColor = UIColor.black
    p.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height:20)
    p.progress = 1.0
    return p
}()
```

So it is natural out of habit, misunderstanding, or abundance of caution to resort to form 3 when in fact there was only one line and all you needed was form 2. It’s an easy mistake and does no harm.

Comment: 'People who do it the second way are making a mistake, that’s all.'  - google 'lazy in swift' and see that 3 of 4 top links (exclude docs.swift.org) contain this mistake https://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+in+swift&oq=lazy+in+swift. (actual for March 16, 2019) Thank you, your answer that is what I needed. But I had voted to close this question.

Comment: I retracted vote to close I didn't know about this ability.

Comment: Well, I prefer my own explanation to what google may say. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_lazy_initialization (where these examples come from) and http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_properties

Comment: my first 4 links: 1. https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/lazy-var-in-ios-swift-96c75cb8a13a 2. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables 3. https://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/ 4. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html - it is when I googled as an anonymous, but when I googled from my account(I am a newcomer in swift) - the 4th link is 2nd. I didn't read docs.swift.org link because of my project is in swift 4.2 but topic about swift 5.