# Swift: why lazy, computed property, and property observer can not be let

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-evaluation, let

I have been searching on why lazy, computed property, and property observer can not be (let) constant, I know for example lazy are not assigned until it is accessed, but why it can not be (let), does that mean lazy will be holding a nil value or whatever value before it's being accessed and assigned to the value we assigned? please explain the same thing for computed property, and property observer.

Comment: you can easily test when it will have a value, just put a `print` inside the `lazy` block. It won't get triggered until you access the value. Before that the value is not even `nil`. It's not ever defined. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515805/difference-between-computed-property-and-property-set-with-closure/50845853#50845853)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lazy properties** : You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.

**computed property** : whereas computed properties calculate (rather than store) a value.  Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

**property observer** : property observers is to monitor changes in a property’s value, if you define it let then how you can monitor changes because let is one type of constant which you can not change after init.

Answer (score 0):

**Rules:-**

1. You can declare a property with either `let` or `var` keyword.
2. In swift, `let` variable must be initialized before the owner of the `let` variable is initialized.
3. Once you assign a value to the `let` variable, you can't change its value again.

**Now let's see all three types of properties one by one:-**

1. lazy variable - It initializes after the owner is initialized. So, rule 2 violates here.
2. computed variable - Whenever you access a computed variable, it returns the value after some calculation/operation. So, rule 3 violates here.
3. property observer - `didSet` or `willSet` of property observer gets called when you change its value. So, rule 3 violates here.

Comment: by the term "owner" do you mean the object?