# what does the line self = self do in swift

Tags: swift

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of self = self in this code?

```
// Keep the reference to the interface :
private var guidedItfRef: Ref<GuidedPilotingItf>?
private var goUp: Bool
...
guidedItfRef = provider.getPilotingItf(PilotingItfs.guided) { [weak self] guidedItf in
    if let guidedItf = guidedItf, let self = self, guidedItf.currentDirective == nil {
        self.goUp = !self.goUp
        guidedItf.moveToRelativePosition(forwardComponent: 0, rightComponent: 0,
                downwardComponent: self.goUp ? 2.0 : -3.0 , headingRotation: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Replace `self.goUp = !self.goUp` with `self.goUp.toggle()` if using newer versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use  `[weak self]` inside a closure this will make `self` to be optional so you need to unwrap it with `let`

```
, let self = self // rhs self is optional , `self` or let strongSelf = self
```

like

```
var value:int?
```

unwrap option 1

```
guard let value = value else { return } 
// use value which now is Int not int?
```

unwrap option 2

```
if let value = value {  
   // use value which now is Int not int?
}
```

Comment: Thanks can you provide a little more detail as I'm new to swift?

Comment: @bakalolo I don't know if I am not understanding you correctly, but [you also said you were new to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31515805/9607863) on `Jul 20 '15` (over 4 years ago).

Comment: @George_E hahahahahahhahahahahaha nice notice

Comment: @Sh_Khan I clicked on their profile after seeing their high score (that post I linked shows as the first on their profile due to its popularity). There are actually older posts they have made about Swift :p