# i cant sent the delegate of the UI search Bar in computed property

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, computed-properties

I recently came across something weird that i can't wrap my head around.

i was using a SearchBar as a UI element. (note: it is the [UIView subclass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar) and not [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/) subclass that apple handily gives out.

But i wasn't able to assign the the delegate in the computed property but was able to in viewDidload().

```
@usesAutoLayout var imageSearchbar:UISearchBar = {
    let bar = UISearchBar()
    bar.delegate = self
    bar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    bar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
    return bar
}()
```

bar.delegate = self shows a compile time error

---

> Cannot assign value of type '(CollectionViewController) -> () ->
> CollectionViewController' to type 'UISearchBarDelegate?'

---

I want to gain knowledge as to what is it that i'm missing.
Help appreciated.

Comment: It's a closure, not a computed property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515805/difference-between-computed-property-and-property-set-with-closure And it looks like CollectionViewController needs UISearchBarDelegate protocol conformance.